# Django: Custom User Model fields not appearing in Django admin

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models

I'm trying to add some extra fields into the `django.contrib.auth.models` User model. I'll be using this custom User model throughout my project. I used `AbstractUser` to add `name` and `contact` fields.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name of User'), blank=True, max_length=255)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

In my `settings.py`, I added to the `apps.authentication`, which is my app:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [ 'apps.authentication', ...]
```

I also specified my `AUTH_USER_MODEL`:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.User'
```

I then ran migrations and it worked (I checked my local db; new tables were made). However, when I access it using the Django admin, the `name` and `contact` fields were nowhere to be found. How do I make the fields appear?

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can append default `UserAdmin` class with custom [fieldsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets) by adding following to `admin.py` file:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

UserAdmin.fieldsets += ('Custom fields set', {'fields': ('name', 'contact')}),
```

Comment: Do you know how to add these fields into the `Personal info` section? I'd  like to just put them there.

Comment: @DonovanKeating since `fieldsets` is immutable, I suppose you'd better to override default `fieldsets` completly, like this `UserAdmin.fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'name', 'contact')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                       'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login',)}),`

Comment: Oh thanks! Just curious, what are those underscores in those tuple-looking things like `(_('Important dates')`?

Comment: @DonovanKeating it's translation tool, which makes string 'Personal info' in following code `_('Personal info')` multilingual. You need to import it like this: `from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _`. `_` is just commonly used synonym. Check related part of the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/ for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I think the part you are missing is registering your user model in the app’s admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import User

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

(taken from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model)

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted solution does work, it puts all the new fields at the very bottom of the page. It's nice to be able to append fields to a specific section, and to move fields from one section to another.

I use these two utility functions for appending fields to a fieldset and moving fields from one fieldset to another:

**common/utils/admin.py**

```
def append_fields(fieldsets, section, fields):
    """
    fieldsets : tuple
        The fieldsets to append to.
            - fieldsets for editing existing objects
            - add_fieldsets for adding new objects
    section : str or None
        The title of the section. None for the titleless section.
    fields : tuple
        The fields being appended.
    """
    for fieldset in fieldsets:
        if fieldset[0] == section:
            fieldset[1]['fields'] += fields
            break 
    else: # Add new section
        fieldsets = fieldsets + (
            (section, {
                'classes': ('wide',),
                'fields': fields
            }),
        )
    return fieldsets

def move_field(fieldsets, field, from_section, to_section):
    """
    fieldsets : tuple
        The fieldsets to append to.
            - fieldsets for editing existing objects
            - add_fieldsets for adding new objects
    field: str
        The name of the field to move.
    from_section : str or None
        The title of the section from which to remove the field.
    to_section : str or None
        The title of the section in which to add the field.
    """
    for fieldset in fieldsets:
        if fieldset[0] == from_section:
            field_list = list(fieldset[1]['fields'])
            field_list.remove(field) # will raise exception if field not found
            fieldset[1]['fields'] = tuple(field_list)
            break
    else:
        raise Exception(f'No such from fieldset: {from_section}')

    for fieldset in fieldsets:
        print(fieldset)
        if fieldset[0] == to_section:
            fieldset[1]['fields'] = fieldset[1]['fields'] + (field, )
            break
    else:
        raise Exception(f'No such to fieldset: {to_section}')
```

Then I import it into my `CustomUserAdmin` class:

**users/admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from common.utils.admin import append_fields, move_field

CustomUser = get_user_model()

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = CustomUser

    # Fields for editing existing user
    new_fields = ('dob', 'avatar')
    fieldsets = append_fields(UserAdmin.fieldsets, 'Personal info', new_fields)
    move_field(UserAdmin.fieldsets, 'email', 'Personal info', None)

    # Fields for adding new user
    new_fields = ('email', )
    optional_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'dob')
    add_fieldsets = append_fields(UserAdmin.add_fieldsets, None, new_fields)
    add_fieldsets = append_fields(
        UserAdmin.add_fieldsets, 'Optional Fields', optional_fields
    )


admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```